# How to prepopulate data-email from separate form

Tags: javascript, html

I am using [Formspree](https://formspree.io/) and Stripe Checkout. I'd like to have whatever's entered into the Formspree form's `<input type="email" name="Customer Email" placeholder="your email here">` be sent to the `data-email="example@mail.com"`. Is this possible? My code looks like this:

```
<!-- Begin Stripe Form -->
<form method="POST">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button" data-key="pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh" data-image="" data-amount="8500" data-name="some co." data-description="Custom Blanket" data-locale="auto"
    data-zip-code="true" data-billing-address="true" data-shipping-address="true" data-email="example@mail.com">
  </script>
  <script>
    document.getElementsByClassName("stripe-button-el")[0].style.display = 'none';
  </script>
  <button type="submit">Done</button>
</form>
<!-- End Stripe Form -->
```

---

```
<!-- Begin Formspree Form -->
<form action="https://formspree.io/xrqjnzam" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display: none">
  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://example.com/blanket/thankyou.html" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Order!" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_cc" value="x@somedomain.com" />
  <!-- <input type="hidden" name="_format" value="plain" /> -->
  <input type="email" name="Customer Email" placeholder="your email here">
  <button hidden type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
<!-- End Formspree Form -->
```

Comment: You can do it by using jquery ATTR funciton.
See this http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: sorry your statement confuses me. you want to send the data in email ? mentioned in data attribute ?

Comment: @UsmanRana I would like to populate the Stripe data-email field from whatever the user types into the Formspree form.

Comment: You mean when the user submits the form the email address should be sent to `data-email`?

Comment: When the user types into the form, yes. I’ll be actually submitting the form later, so only need what’s entered to populate data-email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send the typed email to the `script` elements attribute, you have to add an event-listener.

```
$(function(){
  var $email_field=$('[name="Customer Email"]');
  $email_field.on('change', function(){
    $('#script').attr('data-email', $email_field.val());
  });
});
```

If it doesn't that is because the script is loaded already and initialized with the default email value `mail@example.com`. In that case you need to create the script with JavaScript after user types the email address and insert it into DOM.

```
$(function() {
    var $stripe_form = $('#stripe_form');
    var $email_field = $('[name="Customer Email"]');
    $email_field.on('change', function() {
        $('<script>').attr({
            "src" : "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js",
            "class" : "stripe-button",
            "data-key" : "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh",
            "data-image" : "",
            "data-amount" : "8500",
            "data-name" : "Company",
            "data-description" : "Product",
            "data-locale" : "auto",
            "data-zip-code" : "true",
            "data-billing-address" : "true",
            "data-shipping-address" : "true",
            "data-email" : $email_field.val(),
        }).prependTo($stripe_form);
    });
});
```

But obviously this will add a new `<script>` every-time user changes the email. So it will be better if you hide the email section of your form when user enters the email and confirms it with a button click.

```js
$(function() {
  var $stripe_form = $('#stripe_form');
  var $email_section = $('#email_section');
  var $email_field = $('[name="Customer Email"]');
  var $email_confirm_button = $('#email_confirm_button');
  $email_confirm_button.on('click', function() {
    $email_section.slideUp();
    $stripe_form.show();
    $('<script>').attr({
      "src": "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js",
      "class": "stripe-button",
      "data-key": "pk_test_6pRNASCoBOKtIshFeQd4XMUh",
      "data-image": "",
      "data-amount": "8500",
      "data-name": "Company",
      "data-description": "Product",
      "data-locale": "auto",
      "data-zip-code": "true",
      "data-billing-address": "true",
      "data-shipping-address": "true",
      "data-email": $email_field.val(),
    })
    .prependTo($stripe_form);
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<form action="https://formspree.io/xrqjnzbm" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display: none">
  <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://example.com/thankyou.html" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New Order" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_cc" value="x@example.com" />
  <div id="email_section">
    <input type="email" name="Customer Email" placeholder="your email here">
    <button id="email_confirm_button" type="button">Continue to Payment</button>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" hidden>Send</button>
</form>

<form id="stripe_form" method="POST" style="display:none">
  <button type="submit">Continue to Next Step</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It didn't work. I also tried removing the data-email default, but that didn't seem to work either. Would you mind clarifying what you mean in this fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/r11ohf4c/

Comment: `data-billingAddress` should be `data-billing-address`, `data-shippingAddress` should be `data-shipping-address`

Comment: Fixed to `data-billing-address` and  `data-shipping-address`

Comment: I tried to incorporate your edit above. While it does pass the email to where it needs to go, it opens up a new Stripe button whenever the email field is changed- I only want the "done" button and the form to open as it did in my original example. How can I achieve this? https://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/n83d5h2k/

Comment: Just hide the email section when user put the email. It will be better if you add a button for user to click when they have entered the email correctly, when they click the button, you hide the email section and show the rest of the form

Comment: Okay. I appreciate your help. I will open a new question for the new "done" button issue. Cheers. I will award the bounty when it lets me.

Comment: You don't want to hide the email section? I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would have done it. Assign any id to `script` tag for example

```
<script id="script" .. ></script>
```

Now what you need is to get the `email` value from form field and set to script tag as custom or whatever attribute. Something like

```
var email  = document.querySelector('input[type="email"]').value;
document.getElementById("script").setAttribute('data-email', email);
```

Comment: Hi, I added the JS and assigned `id="script"`, to test, to the Stripe script tag but am having trouble getting it to work. Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong, here? https://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/bueaonnz/